# How's Python GUI development today (Sep/2010)?

Tags: python, user-interface

Last time I saw, GUIs in Python were extremely ugly, how's it today?

(saw some beautiful images on google images, but I don't know if are really Python's)

Comment: It is ugly if you use Tk. But you don't have to use Tk.

Comment: @KennyTM: I can make nice looking GUIs with Tkinter -- the problem has more to do with the skill of the programmer than the toolkit IMO.

Comment: Decent GUIs in Tk are possible, but much more work than e.g. in PyQt/PySide. Qt widgets look very good out of the box, on every major platform.

Comment: The way a widget set looks isn't always the best criteria for picking a toolkit unless you're developing a commercial mass market application. The fact that Tkinter is bundled in, and the fact that it has a remarkably powerful and simple API makes it a very viable choice.

Comment: @Bryan_Oakley as you said, depends on the project..

Comment: I think that it's worth noting that PySide finally seems to have a Windows release out.

Comment: It's doing quite well. Thank you for asking.

Comment: @Bryan: Since Python is not widespread enough that we could rely on most non-programming users to have it installed, most applications have to be packaged anyway. At least Py2exe and cx_Freeze automatically add all used libraries to the executable. So coming bundeled with Python isn't much of an advantage. Also, Tk is not only simple, it's minimalistic. Last I checked, I had to copypast a couple of lines every time I wanted **a friggin' Listbox** to have a scrollbar!

Comment: @Veeti looks like not for XP or above

Comment: @deinan: it's just a difference in design. Tk gives you building blocks rather than complete widgets. Two lines of code to create a scrollbar? Who cares? If that's the price I have to pay to be able to take advantage of the remarkable text widget, the canvas, the elegant pack and grid geometry managers, and the genius of bindtags, it's a tradeoff worth making.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 2.7 and 3.0 ships with the themed tk ("ttk") widgets which look much better than previous versions of Tk (though, honestly, any competent GUI developer can make even older Tk look good). Don't let the people who don't know much about Tk sway you from using it, it's still a very viable toolkit for many, many tasks. You won't be creating a Photoshop clone with it, but how many people write those kinds of apps anyway?

I've been using wxPython for the past year and would still choose Tkinter over it for most tasks. Tkinter is much simpler and in many respects more powerful. The only advantage wxWidgets has is that it has more built-in widgets, but I find many of them a bit buggy and hard to use. For most apps that most people will write, Tkinter is still an excellent choice.

Some screenshots of themed widgets are available here:

http://code.google.com/p/python-ttk/wiki/Screenshots

Here's a screenshot of a Tkinter app that uses the themed widgets on the Mac:

http://www.codebykevin.com/phynchronicity-running.png

Answer (score 2):

Tk is sill is the default GUI toolkit for Python, but it has a theme support from Python 2.7/3.1. It is not as ugly as before.

However, you can use some nice alternatives which still look better (IMHO) and have more functionalities :

- wxPython : maybe the most used, cross platform and all, your applications will look the same as native.
- PyQt or soon PySide : bindings for the Nokia Qt open source framework. There is more than just a GUI toolkit.
- PyGTK : bindings for the GTK+ libraries

Here is more info : http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Comment: "Tk still looks ugly" is highly subjective. Are you aware of the themed widget support in modern versions of Tk?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't. I've just seen in another answer. The version shipped with my Python 2.6 didn't have it. You have to use Python 2.7 or 3.1 to have theme support. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python has bindings for Tk, Qt, GTK, wx, and many more. There's no reason it should be any uglier than another language. You're probably thinking of a gui made with Tk, which has a reputation of being ugly. It's not specific to python, but it might be more common because it's very simple and ships with python by default.

See [Gui Programming](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) on the python wiki for more info.

Comment: -1 for ripping on Tk. Modern versions of tk look quite nice, and use native widgets whenever possible. The "tk is ugly" meme isn't nearly as relevant today as it was 5 years ago.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: Better? I haven't used it personally, only stuff made in it which is invariably hideous. Didn't realize it had gotten better

Comment: @Daenyth: that's one of the problems Tkinter has -- people's perception is based on tools written years ago by amateurs. It has improved a *lot* in the past few years.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I'm judging from recent stuff like gitk for example. It's still quite ugly

Comment: @Daenyth: yes, gitk is ugly. It's not entirely the fault of Tk. The creator of gitk obviously chose to ignore the themed widgets tk has had for a few years now.

Answer (score 1):

I Think the latest Tkinter version offers native look for Macos. WxPython and QT offers native look for macos,windows and linux. GTK is abit ugly and prone to crashes on mac cause of the X11  implentation there.

Of course you could build your own GUI , that something I am trying to do with pygame.Let me clarify , I am not making a GUI library just GUI for my own application. I am making the graphics in the 3d app Blender.

My vote for Generic GUI goes to wxPython, tried it, looks great, easy to use and works like a charm across platforms. You will also find tons of info about it. Integrates well with opengl so if you want to do extreme guis on it , it can do them.

Comment: As far as I know, the latest versions of Gtk do not longer require X11 on Mac OS X, but instead use the native widgets from Cocoa.

Comment: hmm seems your are correct , there has been lots of updating since the last time I checked. Thanks for bringing this to my attention , I think I will give pyGTK another try now.

Comment: Tkinter also offers native windows for Windows. Has done so for many years.